# onclick doesn't display the showdiv options

Tags: html, onclick

When I click on the blank link within href, I should see a list of options which will be hidden otherwise. But with my below code, no action is happening. Please advice. Here is my code so far:

```
<section>
   <p>Testing purpose.</p>
    <blockquote style="text-align: left;">
        Clicking on the blank space <mark><a href="#"   
        onclick="showdiv(option1)">$___</a></mark> shows the options.
    </blockquote>
</section>
    <div id="option1" style="display: none; text-align: left;padding-left: 20px;">
         <input type="radio" onclick="showoption1(this)" name="option1"  value="A"> $1
         <input type="radio" onclick="showoption1(this)" name="option1" value="B"> $2
         <input type="radio" onclick="showoption1(this)" name="option1"value="C"> $3
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript responsible for showing the div?

Comment: can you run your code in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
<section>
   <p>Testing purpose.</p>
    <blockquote style="text-align: left;">
        Clicking on the blank space <mark><a href="#"   
        onclick="showdiv()">$___</a></mark> shows the options.
    </blockquote>
</section>
    <div id="option1" style="display: none; text-align: left;padding-left: 20px;">
         <input type="radio" onclick="showoption1(this)" name="option1"  value="A"> $1
         <input type="radio" onclick="showoption1(this)" name="option1" value="B"> $2
         <input type="radio" onclick="showoption1(this)" name="option1"value="C"> $3
    </div>
```

JS Code:

```
function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('option1').style.display = "block";
}
```